# sidebar pages not opening in shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

My menuItems and menuSubItems do not show up when clicked on. It only stays on the default dashboard body. Please note, those subItems do not yet contain anything in them. I want to be able to open those pages before I include any data there.

I am following the tutorial from this YouTube playlist starting at video 10: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLH6mU1kedUy8c44XiTkGSEKRwojVHtsHm

```
 install.packages(c("shiny","shinydashboard","ggplot2","dplyr"))   
 August <- dataframe("Revenue" = c(150,275,450,890,212,618), 
                    "Team" = c(blue,blue,green,green,gold,gold))
 ui <- shinyUI(
   dashboardPage(
     dashboardHeader(title = "August 2019"),
     dashboardSidebar(
       sidebarMenu(
       menuItem("Dashboard",tabName = "dashboard"),
         menuSubItem("By Team", tabName = "by team"),
       menuItem("item2"),
       menuItem("Raw Data")
     )),
     dashboardBody(
       tabItems(
         tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
                 fluidRow(
                   box(valueBoxOutput("totalrevenue"))
                 )),
           tabItem(tabName = "by team",
                   h1("Numbers by Team")
                   ),
           tabItem(tabName = "by customer",
             h2("Numbers by Customer")
      )))))

 server <- shinyServer(function(input,output){
   total.revenue <- sum(August$Revenue)
   output$totalrevenue <- renderValueBox({
     valueBox(
       formatC(total.revenue, format = "d", big.mark = ',')
       ,paste('Revenue:',total.revenue)
       ,icon = icon("stats", lib = 'glyphicon')
       ,color = "blue")
   })
 })
 shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I just need to be able to flip between pages on the dashboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like `tabName = "by team"` does not like the empty space. You also have to name all your tabs. Try following

```r
ui <- shinyUI(
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "August 2019"),
    dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(
        menuItem("Dashboard",tabName = "dashboard"),
        menuSubItem("By Team", tabName = "byteam"),#remove empty space
        menuItem("item2", tabName = "item2"), #give tab name
        menuItem("Raw Data",tabName = "rawdata") #give tab name
      )),
    dashboardBody(
      tabItems(
        tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
                fluidRow(
                  box(valueBoxOutput("totalrevenue"))
                )),
        tabItem(tabName = "byteam", #remove empty space
                h1("Numbers by Team")
        ),
        tabItem(tabName = "item2",
                h2("Numbers by Customer Tab")
                ),
        tabItem(tabName = "rawdata",
                h2("Raw Data Tab")
        )))))

server <- shinyServer(function(input,output){
  total.revenue <- sum(August$Revenue)
  output$totalrevenue <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      formatC(total.revenue, format = "d", big.mark = ',')
      ,paste('Revenue:',total.revenue)
      ,icon = icon("stats", lib = 'glyphicon')
      ,color = "blue")
  })
})
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Hope that helps!